# Laravel does not show the inserted photo

Tags: php, laravel

**When I add an image, the image does not load**
**A link is formed but when I launch that link it does not display the photo**
**I did `php artisan storage:link`**

**And I get the message**

---

**"The [/opt/lampp/htdocs/cmslaravel/authenti/public/storage]**

**link has been connected to**

**[/opt/lampp/htdocs/cmslaravel/authenti/storage/app/public]**

**The links have been created."**

---

**(public/storage/posts/)**

```
Bs0bxrDcP1SsywqHs5jphnEs0dsKUaFuUh1WdgvY.png
```

---

**(storage/app/public/posts/)**

```
Bs0bxrDcP1SsywqHs5jphnEs0dsKUaFuUh1WdgvY.png
```

**I don't understand what I'm wrong about. Everything should work**

**And I added this to the .env file but they do not help**

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

**If anyone can help me and explain to me what I am wrong with, I tried to rewrite the whole code and work the same**

**I've tried quite a few combinations but they don't help**

---

**View Source Page**

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/Bs0bxrDcP1SsywqHs5jphnEs0dsKUaFuUh1WdgvY.png" alt="">
```

Comment: does view source work. I mean does it display the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `<img src="{{ url('storage/'.$image_name) }}" alt="" />` instead of writing

`<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/Bs0bxrDcP1SsywqHs5jphnEs0dsKUaFuUh1WdgvY.png" alt="">`

Hoepfully now your problem will solve. Anyway, to know more aboout the issue please browse the following link:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/show-images-from-storage-folder

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use [Storage::url](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls), eg:

```
<img src="{{asset(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url($image_name))}}" alt="">
```